# Jquery retrieve an attribute value for the selected rowIndex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event when a table cell is clicked that is fired properly. Then, I am trying to get the row index of that selected cell, but I always get "undefined".

I see the correct rowIndex value from $this object, but how to get it? Seems a basic question but I tried different syntax and javascript and jquery methods and I am not able to get the value.

[image]

html:

[image]

Comment: Is `rowIndex` an attribute/property of the `tr` tag? (what does the HTML example look like?)

Comment: Can I see your HTML?

Comment: Please don't post images of code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex) is a property of the `<tr>` so you'll want to navigate up the DOM hierarchy to retrieve it.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("td").on("click", function() {
    const selectedToolTableIndex = this.closest("tr").rowIndex
    
    console.log("row index", selectedToolTableIndex)
  })
})
```

```css
td { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Row #1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row #2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row #3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you need Internet Explorer support, use this instead as IE does not support [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
var selectedToolTableIndex = $(this).closest("tr").prop("rowIndex")
```

This will use jQuery's [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to navigate to the parent `<tr>`, then retrieve the `rowIndex` property via [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Oh sure thank you. Great, that was the solution!

Comment: @Phil Sir please explain this `jQuery` part with comment for future readers.

Comment: @Phil Sir explain about `jQuery($ => {`

Comment: @Kumar same thing as `jQuery(function($) { ... })`, just with an arrow function instead. See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Comment: @Phil Sir okay for your help.